# No obtiene los checkbox seleccionados con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo esta tabla:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="ubicaciones" style="width: 100%;">
     <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Ubicación</th>
      <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php
      $ubicaciones = Ubicacion::getLista();

      if(is_array($ubicaciones))
      {
        foreach($ubicaciones as $ubicacion)
         {
     ?>
           <tr class="ubicacion">
           <td class="td_ubicacion"><?php echo $ubicacion["ubicacion"]; ?></td>
           <td class="td_chkubicacion">
           <?php
            if($cliente->existeUbicacion($ubicacion["id_ubicacion"]))
            {
           ?>
              <input type="checkbox" class="minimal chkUbicacion" value="<?php echo $ubicacion["id_ubicacion"]; ?>" checked>
           <?php
            }
            else
            {
           ?>
              <input type="checkbox" class="minimal chkUbicacion" value="<?php echo $ubicacion["id_ubicacion"]; ?>">
           <?php
            }
           ?>                  
           </td>
           </tr>
    <?php
      }
     }
    ?>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Y tengo este código *JQuery*:

```
var ubicaciones = [];

$(".chkUbicacion").each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
            ubicaciones.push($(this).val());
});
```

En la tabla visualizo un listado de ubicaciones extraídas de la base de datos,
la tabla usa el **plugin DataTable** el problema es que sólo me toma los *checkbox* de un cierto paginado, por ejemplo si selecciono dos *checkbox* del primer paginado y 2 del segundo paginado, sólo me toma los del primer paginado.

Por qué esta pasando esto??

Se me ocurrió cambiar el código JQuery y ahora lo tengo así:

```
    $(".ubicacion").each(function(){
            if($(this).children(".td_chkubicacion").children(".chkUbicacion").prop("checked"))
                ubicaciones.push($(this).children(".td_chkubicacion").children(".chkUbicacion").val());
   });
```

Lo que sucede con este código es que no encuentra en este caso los *checkbox* hijos, qué tengo mal o qué me falta poner??

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería que lo hagas de la siguiente forma, recorriendo todos los `checkbox` y añadiendo al `array` solo los que estén chequeados:

```
var ubicaciones = [];

$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            ubicaciones.push($(this).val());
        }:            
});
```

Utilizar la función `is` es la forma correcta, ya que siempre devolverá un booleano.

Comment: el problema aquí es que solo me toma los checkbox seleccionados del paginado en el que me encuentro y no el de todos

Comment: He actualizando la respuesta para acercarme a lo solicitado.

Comment: No funciona tu código

Comment: Me excuso, no me percaté de que me faltaron dos puntos en ":checked", valida de nuevo por favor.

Comment: Solo obtiene los del paginado actual yo necesito que obtenga todos los checkbox seleccionados no importa en que paginado se encuentren

Comment: Debería funcionar sin problemas, con el código estamos buscando TODOS los input de la página. Valida que estés escribiendo el código igual.